# Frequency per Week - Dialysis Dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, frequency, frequency-analysis

I have a dialysis dataset running from 1995 - 2014. It has the variables "id", "name", "date" and "modality"

I am interested in the "HD" modality.

The data frame follows this structure:
- Begins April 1995 (then lists month to month till Dec 2014)
- Individuals can be found in multiple months (i.e. Name1 could have received dialysis from Apr 1995 to March 1997; Hence why listed multiple times)
- Each row with a date is a session (I need to work out frequency of sessions per week per patient).

Hope that the above makes sense about what I am trying to do.

Here is an example of data set:

```
id          name       date         modality    
10101650    name1      03-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      05-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      07-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      10-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      12-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      14-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      17-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      19-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      21-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      22-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      24-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      26-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      28-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      03-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      05-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      07-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      10-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      12-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      14-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      17-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      19-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      21-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      24-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      26-Apr-95    HD
10206042    name2      28-Apr-95    HD
10101650    name1      01-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      03-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      05-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      08-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      10-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      12-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      15-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      17-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      19-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      22-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      24-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      26-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      29-May-95    HD
10101650    name1      31-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      01-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      03-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      05-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      08-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      10-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      12-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      15-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      17-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      19-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      22-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      24-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      26-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      29-May-95    HD
10205987    name3      31-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      01-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      03-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      05-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      08-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      10-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      12-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      15-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      17-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      19-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      22-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      24-May-95    HD
10206042    name2      26-May-95    HD
```

As mentioned already I need number of sessions per week per patient. This would be an average as patients can be on dialysis for a few years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do this with `dplyr` and `lubridate` package -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df$week_year <- paste(week(df$date), year(df$date), sep = "-")
filter(df, modality == "HD") %>%
group_by(id, name, week_year) %>%
  summarise(sessions = n()) %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  summarize(avg_sessions_per_week = mean(sessions))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [?]
#         id name  avg_sessions_per_week
#      <int> <chr>                 <dbl>
# 1 10101650 name1                  3.00
# 2 10205987 name3                  2.80
# 3 10206042 name2                  3.00
```

---

Data -

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 
10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 
10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 
10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 
10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 
10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 
10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10101650L, 10205987L, 
10205987L, 10205987L, 10205987L, 10205987L, 10205987L, 10205987L, 
10205987L, 10205987L, 10205987L, 10205987L, 10205987L, 10205987L, 
10205987L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 
10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 10206042L, 
10206042L), name = c("name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", 
"name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", 
"name1", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", 
"name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name1", 
"name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", 
"name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name3", 
"name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", 
"name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", "name2", 
"name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", 
"name2", "name2", "name2", "name2"), date = structure(c(9223, 
9225, 9227, 9230, 9232, 9234, 9237, 9239, 9241, 9242, 9244, 9246, 
9248, 9223, 9225, 9227, 9230, 9232, 9234, 9237, 9239, 9241, 9244, 
9246, 9248, 9251, 9253, 9255, 9258, 9260, 9262, 9265, 9267, 9269, 
9272, 9274, 9276, 9279, 9281, 9251, 9253, 9255, 9258, 9260, 9262, 
9265, 9267, 9269, 9272, 9274, 9276, 9279, 9281, 9251, 9253, 9255, 
9258, 9260, 9262, 9265, 9267, 9269, 9272, 9274, 9276), class = "Date"), 
    modality = c("HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", 
    "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", 
    "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", 
    "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", 
    "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", 
    "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", 
    "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD", "HD")), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "date", "modality"), row.names = c(NA, -65L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it working just had to change the class of date variable from "factor" to "date"